# Perl implicit close resets the $. variable

Tags: perl, file-handling, special-variables

The [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/close.html) for Perl's `close` states that `$.` isn't reset if you use the implicit close done by `open`. I was trying to see exactly what this meant, but couldn't get it to happen. Here's my script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
my @files = qw(test1.txt test2.txt test3.txt);

#try with implicit close
for my $file (@files){
    open my $fh, '<', $file;
    while(<$fh>){
        chomp;
        print "line $. is $_\n";
    }
    #implicit close here
}
```

And here are the contents of all three of the files that are read in:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 8
line 9
line 10
```

Since I don't explicitly call `close`, the implicit `close` should be used (I think) and `$.` shouldn't be reset. However, when I run the script, I get this output, showing that $. is reset:

```
line 1 is line 1
line 2 is line 2
line 3 is line 3
line 4 is line 4
line 5 is line 5
line 6 is line 6
line 7 is line 7
line 8 is line 8
line 9 is line 9
line 10 is line 10
line 1 is line 1
line 2 is line 2
line 3 is line 3
line 4 is line 4
line 5 is line 5
line 6 is line 6
line 7 is line 7
line 8 is line 8
line 9 is line 9
line 10 is line 10
line 1 is line 1
line 2 is line 2
line 3 is line 3
line 4 is line 4
line 5 is line 5
line 6 is line 6
line 7 is line 7
line 8 is line 8
line 9 is line 9
line 10 is line 10
```

It sure looks like it's being reset to me. Is my understanding of the documentation wrong? Can someone show me under what circumstance the implicit `close` will not reset `$.`?

By the way, I'm using Strawberry 5.16.1.

Comment: The posting software apparently deletes trailing `.` characters, so your title looked like "Perl implicit close resets $". I "fixed" it by surrounding the `$.` with backticks (which aren't interpreted in titles, but oh well).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$.` is not actually a global variable, it is an attribute of the most recently read filehandle.  And you are using a new filehandle in each iteration through the loop.

Modifying your code like so "fixes" it:

```
my $fh;
for my $file (@files){
    open $fh, '<', $file;
```

Comment: And it once again "breaks" when when I add `undef $fh` at the end of the outer loop. Thanks!

Comment: Perl's little intricacies never cease to amaze me. +1.

Comment: The main place this comes into play is with the `ARGV` filehandle — when you're using `<>` to read and the file you're reading reaches EOF, perl will re-open `ARGV` to the next file in `@ARGV` without an intervening `close`, so `$.` will keep counting up. The `close ARGV if eof` example in perldoc -f eof will catch this condition and put a `close` between each file so that `$.` refers to the line position in the current file instead.